# Generics: java.lang.String cannot be applied to Student

Tags: java, generics

I am in class and my professor is saying her code works and there is nothing wrong with it and that it must be me. I have looked over her code and copied it word for word like she stated however I am still receiving the error:

> Pair.java:28: set(java.lang.String,java.lang.Double) in Pair cannot be applied to (Student,java.lang.Double)

The part I bolded is the part I receive an error on. Are the set methods incorrect? Because the line with the error goes back to the set methods

This is her code:

Student.java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Student implements Person {
  String id;
  String name;
  int age;

  //constructor
  public Student(String i, String n, int a) {
    id = i;
    name = n;
    age = a;
  }

  public String getID() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name; //from Person interface
  } 

  public int getAge() {
    return age; //from Person interface
  }

  public void setid(String i) {
    this.id = i;
  }

  public void setName(String n) {
    this.name = n;

  }

  public void setAge(int a) {
   this.age = a;
  }

  public boolean equalTo(Person other) {
    Student otherStudent = (Student) other;
    //cast Person to Student
    return (id.equals(otherStudent.getID()));
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "Student(ID: " + id + 
      ",Name: " + name +
      ", Age: " + age +")";
  }
}
```

Person.java

```
import java.io.*;

public interface Person {
  //is this the same person?
  public boolean equalTo (Person other);
  //get this persons name
  public String getName();
  //get this persons age
  public int getAge();
}
```

Pair.java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Pair<K, V> {

  K key;
  V value;
  public void set (K k, V v) {
    key = k;
    value = v;
  }

  public K getKey() {return key;}
  public V getValue() {return value;}
  public String toString() {
    return "[" + getKey() + "," + getValue() + "]";
  }

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    Pair<String,Integer> pair1 = 
      new Pair<String,Integer>();
    pair1.set(new String("height"),new
                Integer(36));
    System.out.println(pair1);
    Pair<String,Double> pair2 = 
      new Pair<String,Double>();

    //class Student defined earlier
    **pair2.set(new Student("s0111","Ann",19),**
              new Double(8.5));
    System.out.println(pair2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Should be `Pair<Student,Double> pair2 = new Pair<Student,Double>();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the instantiation:

```
Pair<String,Double> pair2 = new Pair<String,Double>();
```

your `set()` method signature is equivalent to: `set(String, Double)`. And you are passing it a `Student` reference in the below invocation, which wouldn't work, as `Student` is not a `String`.

```
pair2.set(new Student("s0111","Ann",19), new Double(8.5));
```

To avoid the issue, change the declaration of `pair2` to:

```
Pair<Student,Double> pair2 = new Pair<Student,Double>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty self explanatory. pair2 is defined as a `Pair<String, Double>`. You're trying to set a `Student, Double`. That won't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
Pair<String,Double> pair2 = new Pair<String,Double>();
```

should be:

```
Pair<Student,Double> pair2 = new Pair<Student,Double>();
```

Answer (score 1):

from your code `pair2` is defined as type `Pair<String,Double>`,i.e `pair2` `set()` method expecting `String` ,`Double` as arguments,but you are passing `Student` , `Double`.
So

```
Pair<String,Double> pair2 = new Pair<String,Double>();
```

should be

```
Pair<Student,Double> pair2 = new Pair<Student,Double>();
```